# R dataframe how to format specific string to datetime

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with > 1.000.000 rows. In the first column there is "date and time" in the following format:

```
2017.07.04 13:20:38
```

How can I change the format to a posix format, so that I can plot those values as x axis?

I already tried

```
df$V1 <- str_replace_all(df$V1, ".", "-")
```

It replaced more than the dot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another solution from the `tidyverse`:

```r
date <- "2017.07.04 13:20:38"
lubridate::ymd_hms(date)
#> [1] "2017-07-04 13:20:38 UTC"
```

<sup>Created on 2018-09-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

You can provide a `format` argument to `as.POSIXct`:

```
As.POSIXct(df$V1, format = "%Y.%m.%d %H:%M:%S")
```

The `format` argument defines how the string should be interpreted as a datetime, and the `%Y` etc. symbols identify specific components of the datetime. There are lots of formatting options and symbols available. See `?as.POSIXct` for more info.